# How to fix SVG marker orientation in MS Edge?

Tags: svg, microsoft-edge

Trying a basic example from Mozilla Docs and the top arrow is not oriented correctly (only in Ms Edge browser) : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/orient

Is there any way to fix it for that browser?

[image: Top arrow not correctly aligned]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently `orient="auto-start-reverse"` doesn't work in edge so you will need to use `orient="auto"`. For this instead of a `polyline` I'm using 2 lines with the origin in 10,90

```css
svg{width:300px}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <marker id="arrow" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="5" refY="5"
        markerWidth="6" markerHeight="6"
        orient="auto-start-reverse">
      <path d="M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 z" />
    </marker>

    <marker id="dataArrow" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="5" refY="5"
        markerWidth="6" markerHeight="6"
        orient="-65deg">
      <path d="M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 z" fill="red" />
    </marker>
  </defs>




  <line x1="10" y1="90" x2="90" y2="90" fill="none" stroke="black"
      marker-end="url(#arrow)" marker-end="url(#arrow)" />
  <line x1="10" y1="90" x2="10" y2="10" fill="none" stroke="black"
      marker-end="url(#arrow)" marker-end="url(#arrow)" />
  
  <polyline points="15,80 29,50 43,60 57,30 71,40 85,15" fill="none" stroke="grey"
      marker-start="url(#dataArrow)" marker-mid="url(#dataArrow)"
      marker-end="url(#dataArrow)" />
</svg>
```

See this pen: https://codepen.io/AmeliaBR/details/qjXoQd

*"auto-start-reverse SVG marker ...... Doesn't work in Edge/IE (and other older browsers) and doesn't fallback nicely (you get a non-rotating marker instead)."*

Comment: I saw one svg nested in another svg. And markers with the same ID. When I deleted one SVG application it remained working. Is this correct or a mistake?

Comment: thank you very much @Alexandr_TT. I've corrected the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much @enxaneta for your response. A random typo gave me some interesting thoughts about implementing other solutions not related to this answer